# How to fix wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress

Hi everyone, I download a project from the server to my local directory where I have other Wordpress projects and they work perfectly.

I change the database and the configure.php file but when I try to view the page I get this error.

wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server

Any ideas?

Comment: It's very hard to answer anything based on this, and only possible to throw guesses. Please provide more information if you want us to help.

Comment: Thanks @Roope Finally I do it, the database had a error!!!